# Is there any practical difference between an extension method on <T> or on Object?

Tags: c#

Is there any practical difference between these two extension methods?

```
class Extensions
{
    public static void Foo<T>(this T obj) where T : class { ... }
    public static void Foo(this object obj) { ... }
}
```

I was poking around in [Extension Overflow](http://extensionoverflow.codeplex.com/) and I came across the first form, which I haven't used before. Curious what the difference is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extension methods on `Object` will also apply to value types.  (And they'll be boxed by the call, reducing performance)

Extension methods on `<T>` but without `where T : class` will also work on value types, but will not box them.

In addition, extension methods on `<T>` can write `typeof(T)` to get the *compile-time* type of their invocation.
If you do that, note the difference between

```
someButton.Extension();
someButton.Extension<Control>();
someButton.Extension<Object>();
```

Comment: Also, the method will know the type of the argument, even if it is `null`, when using the generic version. Might matter, or it might not.